# Solaris 11 pool growing without any apparent cause

Tags: zfs, snapshot, solaris-11

One of my zfs pools is growing very large:

```
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zonepool01   556G   535G  21.2G  96%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

`df -h` shows that the largest mount point on this pool has 6 files in the directory so files are not the issue.

I looked for old snapshots:

```
zfs list -t snapshot -o name -S creation | grep 2015 | grep zonepool01

zonepool01/server06/rpool/ROOT/solaris-3@2015-09-24-03:10:49
zonepool01/server06/rpool/ROOT/solaris-3/var@2015-09-24-03:10:49
zonepool01/server05/rpool/ROOT/solaris-3@2015-09-24-03:10:45
[...]
zonepool01/server28/rpool/ROOT/solaris-3@2015-08-12-17:02:10
zonepool01/server27/rpool/ROOT/solaris-0/var@2015-08-12-16:55:37
zonepool01/server27/rpool/ROOT/solaris-3@2015-08-12-16:55:37
```

The last time I tried to delete snapshots I messed up my boot and system. To prevent this, I need to know:

- How do I know what is old and obsolete?
- How do I know what is not referenced by other snaps?
- How do I stop this auto snap feature?

Comment: Automatic snapshots have the name zfs-auto-snap in them. Googling for solaris automatic snapshot yields several articles with useful info about how to manage this.